# Linux: can't resolve any hostname

Tags: linux, networking, dns, wget, hostname

I am having a Debian server and it can't resolve any hostname, like with `wget`. Unfortunately I can't even install any packages, so I can't install the `host` command or similar. I am not an expert for Linux or Linux networking and don't know what to do.
Here is my nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:         files
group:          files
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

because in many examples in the first 3 rows, there was `compat` written, instead of `files`, I allready tried that, but nothing changed.

resolv.conf:

```
domain localdomain
search localdomain
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: What distro? What is the contents of /etc/resolv.conf ? Are you running a GUI?

Comment: Distro is "Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)" (pretty name), I added resolv.conf to the Question and I am not running a GUI! Hope you can work with that!

Comment: If you (temporarily) change the nameserver to 1.1.1.1 do things start working for you?

Comment: Yes it does work, arp gives me 194.62.6.1, should it be that?

Comment: Tried that, it should not!

Comment: ?? Sorry, I don't understand your last statement.   It sounds to me like your router is behaving like a bridge - and that the nameserver running on it is not working on it.   If replacing the nameserver with 1.1.1.1 works, the issue is with your nameserver, not your computer.

Comment: Well, it is not my router, the server is hosted (serverdiscounter.com) and not at my place, but it seams like I am bypassing the nameserver of the router now, right? But when it works it doesn't really metter to me, or is there something I have to be careful with, because you told me, to do it "temporarily"?